# Is CAML process at client side, sharepoint server or sql server?

Tags: caml-query, caml, infrastructure

I am now working on some SSRS reports with Report builder 3.0. I built a datasource with CAML to query (and joined) data from SharePoint lists. In production environment there are over 50,000 records to be queried. I am worrying about the actual performance.

May I know the query process is actually occur at client side, SP servers or SQL servers? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Below URL may help you to understand this process

http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2010/03/18/how-to-avoid-the-top-5-sharepoint-performance-mistakes/

In This they have explained how CAML query works and other things related to getting items

CAML queries are converted to SQL queries using XML to define SQL queries in SP Server and it will send this to SQL server to get the data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68594)

Comment: Please provide details from that url and then provide reference link as if reference link will be unreachable or deleted from the web in future then your answer will be useless.

Comment: its a very big article so i just mentioned the link and gave the main cause.